# Как обратиться из виртуальной машины vagrant к моей локальной машине, на которой запускается vagrant

Tags: vagrant

ОС: Windows 10

Запускаю бекенд проекта в vagrant машине, а фронтенд - локально.
Делаю так, что бы при разработке фронтенда работал live reload. Т.к. если запускать фронтенд внутри vagrant - то система не видит производимых изменений.

Так вот. Как мне из vagrant обратиться по IP к моей локальной машине?

Comment: В VirtualBox какой тип сетевого адаптера выбран?

Comment: Да, прошу прощение. Проблема как оказалась была не в vagrant'е и здесь действительно было достаточно обратиться по IP машины. Дело было в принимающем сервере, он отклонял запросы и мне казалось, что я не могут обратиться из vagrant к своей машине.

Answer (score 0):

Обращайся по ip-адресу компьютера в локальной сети.

Comment: *Капитан Очевидность, вы ли это?* :-)

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание на следующий фрагмент вопроса: *"Как мне из vagrant обратиться по IP к моей локальной машине?"*

Comment: @PavelMayorov я не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Я тоже не вижу проблемы, но ответ от этого полезнее не становится

Comment: @PavelMayorov IP означает протокол интернета, в ответе я указал, что для доступа к компьютеру нужно указан адрес протокола интернета. Да, это если трактовать вопрос буквально. Также я указал по какому именно ip-адресу нужно обращаться.

Comment: Да, прошу прощение. Проблема как оказалась была не в vagrant'е и здесь действительно было достаточно обратиться по IP машины. Дело было в принимающем сервере, он отклонял запросы и мне казалось, что я не могут обратиться из vagrant к своей машине.

Answer (score 0):

Да, прошу прощение. Проблема как оказалась была не в vagrant'е и здесь действительно было достаточно обратиться по IP машины. Дело было в принимающем сервере, он отклонял запросы и мне казалось, что я не могут обратиться из vagrant к своей машине.

Comment: Надо было пропинговать.